# Como contar quantos dias de um certo tipo (segunda, sexta etc.) existem entre duas datas?

Tags: java

Como faço para saber quantos dias de semana de tipos específicos (por exemplo: apenas segundas, terças e quartas) existem entre duas datas em Java?

Por exemplo, da data 01/12 até 30/12, quantas `segundas, terças e quartas` existem entre elas?

Comment: Usando um lib com por exemplo joda-time, pode fazer como nesse post aqui, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda-time

Comment: Vc quer contar os dias entre duas datas, porém ignorando determinados dias da semana na contagem, seria isso?

Comment: Ele quer contar quantos "segundas, terças e quartas" existem de uma data D até uma data D+N.

Comment: isso, quero contar quantas segundas, terças e quartas existem apartir de uma data X até uma data Y

Comment: @LR10, o link que passou fala somente como contar dias entre duas datas, sem levar em conta o detalhe que mencionei, (editei minha resposta)...

Comment: @felipe.rce Veja se a minha edição está de acordo com o que você está querendo.

Comment: [Veja esse exemplo no IdeOne](https://ideone.com/5wAgRH) @felipe.rce. Utilizando somente Java.

Comment: @GustavoCinque é isso mesmo que eu queria!

Comment: LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate(2017, 11, 01);
  LocalDate endDate = new LocalDate(2017, 11, 30)
 
  Days days = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays() ;

Comment: Você pode fazer um for em days e pegar o getDayOfWeek() por exemplo e contar os dias. É um sugestão. Como aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338196/joda-time-get-week-days

Comment: É assim mesmo @LR10, chegou a ver o exemplo que eu coloquei?

Comment: estou aguardando reabrirem (não sei porque fecharam, já que foi editado antes de ser fechado) para que eu possa aceitar a resposta